# Suppress warning:deleting 'void*' is undefined

Tags: c++11, suppress-warnings, gcc-warning

I know what is this warning and need to suppress this warning. Is there any way using pragma or compiler options are available to suppress this warning?

Comment: This sounds like the kind of warning you really shouldn't suppress. Why are you trying to delete a `void *`?

Comment: This is usually caused by improper handling of ownership. The person who allocates the memory should be the person who deletes it. Since you knew the type when you allocated the memory you should know it when you delete the memory. Why are you using void * in C++.

Comment: You shouldn't have "void * p = new void" anywhere, so why do you want to delete a void pointer? Stop messing with the type system. You're probably using too many pointers

Comment: Suppose you have a method which allocates, via new, one of 10 or more different object types, based on a condition, then stores that new object in a variable of type void*.  When use is complete, another method is called to delete the object. Do you just delete the memory in the void* or do you go through a similar allocation type check and implement 10+ different delete calls? If the former works and the warning can be silenced, it's a cleaner solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Better to change the code to avoid this warning rather than suppressing it!
If not handled correctly, it may cause runtime surprises which will be much harder to find.

[Note: To answer your question, which should be taken with a grain of salt, you may use `free()` instead of `delete`, as it converts any pointer to `void*` before deallocating it. Make sure that the destructors are called correctly before it.]

Answer (score 1):

Just cast it before the delete.

```
delete[] (char*)item_to_del;
```

Comment: How exactly are you guessing that the correct type is `char`?

Comment: It's not a matter of what the correct type, but a question how to suppress the compiler warning.
There is no "right type".

Comment: of course there is a right type -- the one that has been `new`ed, or a polymorphic one suitable for deallocation. You're trading one UB for another.